# error with SQL commands in Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am working on my graduation project. I is a Java application that connects to a database. I want to apply search in database with combobox when user select item the result will shows in JTable I wrote the code but I don't know what is wrong with my SQL command it throw this exception

```
    أبر 18, 2016 5:03:32 م MyQuery getData
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][?????? ????? ODBC Microsoft Access] ??? ?? ???? ?????? (???? ??????? ?????) ?? ????? ??????? '`CAT_NAME`=    Human Resources'.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:252)
    at MyQuery.getData(MyQuery.java:33)
    at Travel1.jComboBoxCat1ActionPerformed(Travel1.java:177)
    at Travel1.access$100(Travel1.java:33)
    at Travel1$3.actionPerformed(Travel1.java:137)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:588)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:624)
```

This is my code:

```
private void jComboBoxCat1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
MyQuery mq = new MyQuery();
    ArrayList<Course> list = mq.getData((String)jComboBoxCat1.getSelectedItem());
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Course Name","Duration","FEES","City","Category"});
    Object[] row = new Object[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        row[0] = list.get(i).getCourse_Name();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getDuration();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getFEES();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getCourse_Date();
        row[4] = list.get(i).getCity();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
    jTableresult.setModel(model);
```

MyQuery Class

```
public ArrayList<Course> getData(String catName){

ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<Course>();
Connection con = getConnection();
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

try {
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT  `   COURSE_NAME`,`DURATION`,`FEES`,`DATE_FROM`,`C_NAME`,CAT_NAME FROM `Course` WHERE `CAT_NAME`= " + catName);
Course p;
while(rs.next()){
p = new Course(
rs.getString("COURSE_NAME"),
rs.getInt("DURATION"),
rs.getInt("FEES"),
rs.getString("DATE_FROM"),
rs.getString("C_NAME"),
rs.getString("CAT_NAME")
);
list.add(p);
}

} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Travel1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return list;
}
```

}

Comment: Microsoft Access doesn't use the backtick to quote column names.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a Swing problem. It is an SQL problem.

So first you create a method to do an SQL query and return a ResultSet. Then you hard code all the data to get the SQL working. Then you add in the logic that does the dynamic query by getting the search string from the combo box. The idea is to simplify the problem and concentrate on the direct error.

Regarding the problem I have a couple of suggestions:

1) I have never use the quotes around the individual column names so I don't know if they are needed. In any case I would remove the leading spaces before the "Course_Name" in the SQL.

2) Use a PreparedStatement. It allows you to specify parameters for your variables in the SQL string and will then format the SQL using these variables so you don't have to worry about the formatting. A basic example:

```
String sql = "Select * from SomeTable where SomeColumn = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, someColumnVariable);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next())
{
    // do something
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your sql statment should look like this

String sql = "Select column_name From table_name Where column_name = 'text';

Comment: (1-) That is not how you code a where clause when you use variables. See the simple example below that uses a PreparedStatement which is what you should also be using to simply the query.